# Unable to resize image with cv2

Tags: python, numpy, keras, opencv

I'm trying to resize cifar10 image set from 32x32 to 96x96.

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = cifar10.load_data()

train_images_reshaped = np.array((50000, 96, 96, 3,))
for a in range(len(train_images)):
    train_images_reshaped[a] = cv2.resize(train_images[a], dsize=(96, 96), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

But am getting the error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What's going wrong? Any alternatives besides this to achieve my goal?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems like you're trying to create an n-dimensional array (ndarray) of 50K*96*96*3, but `array` that you're using returns an actual array, of 4 values. Try to look into `ndarray` instead, but note that that amount of space won't necessarily be available due to memory allocations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to do

```
train_images_reshaped = np.zeros((50000, 96, 96, 3,))
```

instead of

```
train_images_reshaped = np.array((50000, 96, 96, 3,))
```

Comment: ```np.zeros``` will create an array of doubles. The memory consumption is increased 8-fold. I strongly suggest adding argument ```dtype=np.uint8``` or using ```np.zeros_like``` function like in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You initialize train_images_reshaped wrong, it is an ndarray of shape (50000, 96, 96, 3,), not array of (50000, 96, 96, 3,).
Try this:

```
train_images_reshaped = np.zeros_like(train_images, shape=(50000, 96, 96, 3,))
```